# How is the "common practice period" (1650-1900) called in German musicology?

Tags: translation, music

Is there a commonly used translation in German musicology for the term 'common practice period'?

I couldn’t find a translation to German for ‘common practice’ except the naming of the 3 epoques:

It is about the period 1650-1900 and meant the common language of the composers among themselves and the audience (tonality, harmony, rhythm, notation etc) of Baroque-Classic-Romanticism.

Can these three eras be summarized under the term "Klassische Musik"?

Comment: I cleaned up the comments. Please be aware of the following: 1) [Asking in German has always been completely fine.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/2594). If anybody claims otherwise, refer them to said FAQ or flag the respective comment. 2) Users being able to format each others posts is one of the core tenets of this site. [If you are not comfortable with this, this may not be the site for you.](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/editing). 3) Please [be nice](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: @Wrzlpmft, danke, das ist sehr freundlich von dir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call the *common practice period* *Klassische Musik* and the man on the street wouldn't bat an eye, even though it's technically incorrect.

The *[common practice period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_practice_period)* covers the eras of Baroque, Classical and Romantic music, spanning from ~1600 to ~ 1910.

The German term *[Klassische Musik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klassische_Musik)* includes these eras and their predecessor the Renaissance, extending the time slot to ~1400.

As you said there seems to be **no (official) German term**. Articles or books in German use the English term without translating it. Like [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=mxaQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA270&lpg=PA270&dq=common-practice%20period.&source=bl&ots=EmWNFfoggk&sig=ACfU3U0un4Joyn45TyqTbE8Vp_wJaDHn4g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLvaG_p5jiAhWCI1AKHdLvAckQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=common-practice%20period.&f=false), [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=7KR5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=common-practice%20period.&source=bl&ots=0GVVdfCIiK&sig=ACfU3U2ZLWBEuggTcAaWa5E-GHkWWWWQ3Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWwv3Rp5jiAhUYwcQBHZ5aA9s4ChDoATADegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=common-practice%20period.&f=false) or [this one](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wNmbmGGFdOUJ:https://www.gmth.de/zeitschrift/artikel/992.aspx%20&cd=18&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&lr=lang_de).

---

But what if ... we make one up?

English [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_practice_period) says

> In the history of European art music, the common practice period is the era of the tonal system.

So let's call it

> Die Ära/das (Haupt-) Zeitalter der [Tonalität](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonality)/(der [Tonalen Musik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonalit%C3%A4t_(Musik)))

or just take it literally

> Die normale/übliche Periode (der klassischen Musik)

or as one of the [books](https://books.google.de/books?id=7KR5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=common-practice%20period.&source=bl&ots=0GVVdfCIiK&sig=ACfU3U2ZLWBEuggTcAaWa5E-GHkWWWWQ3Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWwv3Rp5jiAhUYwcQBHZ5aA9s4ChDoATADegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=common-practice%20period.&f=false) cited above said

> Klassische europäische Instrumentalmusik

Comment: I consider the last one, even if a citation, wrong: *common practice* also covers choral music. Still, +1

Comment: Die Antwort auf diese Frage habe ich nun wirklich nicht gewusst:   also vielleicht **die Zeit der Dur-Moll-Tonalität** (inklusive Notenschrift, Rhythmus, Sonatenform, Instrumental-Musik und - später noch Wohltemperierung?)

Comment: Ich bin mit der Übersetzung von _tonal system_ als _Tonalität_ nicht ganz einverstanden. Ich würde ja davon ausgehen, dass europäische Musik auch vor der Rennaissance schon _tonal_ war. (Damit folgt sie, ob bewusst oder nicht, zu der Zeit natürlich schon _einem_ Tonsystem, aber nicht, wie auf dem englischen Wiki, _dem_ Tonsystem. (Sondern, soweit ich weiß, vor allem einem pentatonischen.))

Comment: Ein anderes Problem mit dem Ausdruck "klassische Musik" ist natürlich, dass der Mann auf der Straße darunter auch etwa Zwölftonmusik, und grundsätzlich vermutlich jede Art von E-Musik (auch, sagen wir, Gershwin), womöglich aber nicht Filmmusik verstehen würde; das scheint mir jede Übersetzung, die sich auf Charakteristika der Musik statt die Epochen selbst bezieht, sehr zu erschweren.

Answer (score -3):

There isn't obviously a German term or translation to German for ‘common practice’ except the naming of the 3 epoques. But when looking up this link

This article is about Western art music to the present.

*Classical music is art music produced or rooted in the traditions of Western culture, including both liturgical (religious) and secular music. While a more precise term is also used to refer to the period from 1750 to 1820 (the Classical period), this article is about the broad span of time from before the 6th century AD to the present day, which includes the Classical period and various other periods.[1]*

**The central norms of this tradition became codified between 1550 and 1900, which is known as the common-practice period.**

Ich gebe jetzt meine Antwort auf Deutsch. dass ich die Frage auf englisch gestellt habe war ein Missverständnis der Spielregeln...

**Bearbeitet:**

Es gibt offensichtlich keinen deutschen Begriff oder eine Übertragung ins Deutsche für ‚common practice‘, mit Ausnahme der Benennung der drei Epochen "Barock, Kassik und Romantik" - und common practice meint, alles was für diese Zeit gemeinsame, "gängige Praxis" war, nämlich:

Insbesondere ein tonales Dur-Moll-System mit einem tonalen Zentrum,  die gängigen Tonarten und Tonleitern, die Kadenz von Tonika-Subdominante-Dominante-Tonika, die gemeinsame Harmonik (inklusive Generalbass) die allgemeinen Formen wie Lied, Suiten, Sonaten, Fugen, Orchesterkonzerte und Solokonzerte, Kammermusik, Streichquartette, der vierstimmige Satz, die allgemeinen Stimmführungsregeln, und insbesondere auch die Notation in einem oder mehreren Notensystemen bestehend aus 5 Linien mit Notenschlüsseln, die Notenwerte und üblichen Taktarten. Also kurz gesagt: in etwa das, was der "normale Mensch" unter "normaler Musik" versteht. Ich finde den Ausdruck sehr unglücklich gewählt und es ist schade, dass keiner meiner amerkikanischen Freunde in der Lage war mir eine Erklärung zu geben. Vielleicht könnte man sagen: **"allgemein verständliche Musik".**

Comment: Can you merge this into your question please. It is not meant as answer, isn't it?

Comment: no, this is the answer.

Comment: The answer part of this is "I couldn’t find a translation to German for ‘common practice’ except the naming of the 3 epoques.", plus maybe the part before that.

Comment: That's an answer about an English term, so I don't think it fits on German.SE.

Comment: Was jetzt? Wenn ich hier auf Deutsch antworte, heisst es, ich solle gefälligst auf englisch antworten. Es gibt offensichtlich keine deutsche Übersetzung für  "common practice period". Wie ,wo und wen soll man denn fragen, wenn nicht hier?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: So weit ich es verstanden habe: englische Frage, englische Antwort. Deutsche Frage, deutsche Antwort. Sprache für den gesuchten Begriff Deutsch. D.h., ich kann auf englisch fragen, um einen deutschen Begriff erklärt zu bekommen und die Antwort sollte dann auf englisch sein. Oder deutsch fragen für deutschen Begriff mit Antwort in Deutsch. Einen englischen Begriff erklärt zu bekommen, das ist Teil von Englisch.SE (oder so)

Comment: @ Shegit Brahm: vielen Dank, also jetzt wird mir manches klar. Nichts für ungut.

Comment: @sgf: Ich glaube, du hast mein Problem nicht verstanden. Ich spreche Deutsch und   kann offensichtlich nicht so gut englisch, dass ich mit "common practice period" etwas anfangen kann. Darum frage ich hier: was bedeutet common practice period auf Deutsch? Ich will also fragen, ob jemand weiss, was das auf Deutsch heisst. Und dann bin ich auf eine  mögliche Antwort gestossen ...  Und jetzt bin ich hier am falschen Ort?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Nein, die Frage ist gut, und ich habe sie upgevotet. Deine Antwort beantwortet nur die Frage nicht, sondern erzählt uns etwas über den englischen Ausdruck. Dass "common-practice period" ungefähr mit dem äquivalent ist, was wir auf Deutsch Klassik (im weiteren Sinne) nennen, wissen wir ja schon aus der Frage. Falls dich interessiert, wie man einen Ausdruck wie "common-practice period" übersetzen könnte, also nicht wofür er steht, sondern was seine Bestandteile bedeuten, ist das eine legitime Frage, aber dann ist der Platz dafür nicht eine Antwort auf eine andere Frage.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Die Antwort wäre übrigens entweder so etwas wie "Periode der gemeinsamen Praxis" oder "Periode der allgemeinen Praxis". Beides ist so maximal vage, dass man schon wissen muss, was der Begriff heißt, um zu wissen, was er heißt.

Comment: Danke, soviel hätte ich auch gewusst: also das wäre die wörtliche Übersetzung. Aber wäre ja nicht gesagt was gemeint ist. Es ist auch nicht die "allgemeine Aufführungspraxis", diesen Begriff kennt man auch. Ich habe gefragt: Gibt es einen deutschen Begriff für "common practice period" und der deutsche Linke oben enthält die Antwort auf diese Frage, bzw. sagt was damit gemeint ist. Weshalb man diese Antwort nun downvotet  ist mir völlig unklar. Oder man wüsste dann eine bessere Antwort. (Diese hier ist übrigens praktisch identisch mit der einzigen anderen Antwort.

Comment: Na ja, eine Antwort sollte ja selbst die Antwort enthalten, nicht nur einen Link zu einer Seite, die eine Antwort enthält. (Hier ja auch nicht, dass der Link die entsprechende Antwort enthält.) Einem ist beim Durchlesen also einfach nicht klar, dass diese Antwort die Antwort: "Ja, man kann das Klassische Musik nennen" gibt, daher wusste ich gar nicht, dass sie mit der obigen identisch ist. Du sagst ja hier nur explizit (1), dass es keinen offensichtlichen deutschen Ausdruck gibt, der dasselbe leistet, und (2), dass du hier eine interessante Erklärung zum englischen Ausdruck findest.